# Htmlunit getByXPath not returning image tags

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to search all image tags on a specific page. An example page would be www.chapitre.com

I am using the following code to search for all images on the page:

```
HtmlPage page = HTMLParser.parseHtml(webResponse, webClient.openWindow(null,"testwindow"));
List<?> imageList = page.getByXPath("//img");
ListIterator li = imageList.listIterator();

while (li.hasNext() ) {
    HtmlImage image = (HtmlImage)li.next();
    URL url = new URL(image.getSrcAttribute());

    //For now, only load 1X1 pixels
    if (image.getHeightAttribute().equals("1") && image.getWidthAttribute().equals("1")) {
System.out.println("This is an image: " + url + " from page " + webRequest.getUrl() );
}
```

}

This doesn't return me all the image tags in the page. For example, an image tag with attributes "src="http://ace-lb.advertising.com/site=703223/mnum=1516/bins=1/rich=0/logs=0/betr=A2099=[+]LP2" width="1" height="1"" should be captured, but its not. Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help is really appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because

```
URL url = new URL(image.getSrcAttribute());
```

Is throwing you an exception :)

Try this code:

```
public Main() throws Exception {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.chapitre.com");
    List<HtmlImage> imageList = (List<HtmlImage>) page.getByXPath("//img");
    for (HtmlImage image : imageList) {
        try {
            new URL(image.getSrcAttribute());
            if (image.getHeightAttribute().equals("1") && image.getWidthAttribute().equals("1")) {
                System.out.println(image.getSrcAttribute());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You didn't see this comming :)");
        }
    }
}
```

You can even get those 1x1 pixel images by xpath.

Hope this helps.